# Differencies between mesos-agent binary

Tags: build, dcos

I installed OpenDC/OS 1.9, I found there are some differencies between mesos binaries. In my OpenDC/OS's agent node,  it stores mesos-agent binary under:/opt/mesosphere/packages/mesos--aaedd03eee0d57f5c0d49c74ff1e5721862cad98/bin/

```
[root@localhost mesosphere]# ls -lh packages/mesos--aaedd03eee0d57f5c0d49c74ff1e5721862cad98/bin/
total 1.8M
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 5.0K Mar 24 07:46 make_disk_resources.py
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  44K Mar 24 07:46 mesos
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 278K Mar 24 07:46 mesos-agent
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4.6K Mar 24 07:46 mesos-cat
........
```

mesos-agent size is only 278K

I follow below steps to build mesos source code(same version as above),
http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted
I got all binary and other files under xx/build/src/.libs folder：

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2.0M Jun 20 06:50 mesos-agent
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 781K Jun 20 06:49 mesos-containerizer
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 4.7M Jun 20 06:50 mesos-docker-executor
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3.5M Jun 20 06:48 mesos-execute
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3.8M Jun 20 06:49 mesos-executor
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 2.4M Jun 20 06:48 mesos-fetcher
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 3.1M Jun 20 06:49 mesos-health-check
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1.6M Jun 20 06:48 mesos-local
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 591K Jun 20 06:48 mesos-log
```

this mesos-agent size is more than 2.0M

what's the differencies between these two mesos-agent? Can I replace the first mesos-agent binary（278K） with my self build one(2.0M)  ?
if I install mesos by apt-get install or yum install, the mesos-agent size is almost the same as first one (278K)
How does OpenDC/OS build and use mesos ?

thanks!